# Android Bug Report

Tags: java, android, bug-reporting

My app is crashing randomly and I dont know why.

I saw that there are apps that when there is a force close, you can choose between force close and report.

How can I add it to my application?
Thank you
Ron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite is BugSense. Good user interface, good report details, open source client library or use with ACRA.

http://bugsense.com/

Answer (score 6):

I think the best approach in your case is to have the crashes reported automatically in the background as soon as one occurs.

This is achievable through integrating a product like [Instabug](https://instabug.com).
It offers you a plenty of details regarding every crash including the crash stack trace, all network/console logs, an environment snapshot, and visual reproduction steps.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. I'm glad to help if you have any questions.

Answer (score 5):

That will be shown to users automatically when your app is delivered via Android market. Although personally, I ACRA because it gives you more information and you can use it regardless of whether the app is distributed via market or not e.g. for beta testing.

http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Answer (score 0):

I think that comes automatically when you've uploaded your app to the market. 
If one of your users decide to report it instead of choosing force close you should get a report in your admin panel (https://market.android.com/publish/Home) Next to the price of the app in question you should find a link called something like error(X) where X is the number of different error reports sent to you.

You could also look into this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/

It's something you can add to your app that makes it sent the stack trace to your server. I find this one use full sometimes!

//André

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a little old, I guess it’s useful to refresh the information. ACRA is good, but I would also recommend you to try Crashlytics. It has a very simple interface. Thanks to the simplicity, you can easily install and use this tool. It allows not only making ordinary crash reports but also catching NDK crashes.

Here is a comprehensive review of different helpful bug and crash reporting tools for those who are curious in details: http://cases.azoft.com/report-bugs-effectively-mobile-app-testing-tools/